# Excel Formula not replicating

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have applied a formula to one cell of first row, but when I double click the right bottom corner, excel returns the answer to cell one across the entire column instead of the appropriate answer for that cell. The formula is corresponding alright, but not the answers. Kindly help

Comment: Could you post your formula and describe your worksheet structure (and/or post a screenshot)? Thanks.

Comment: It's a countif formula..work thing, can't post screenshot.

Comment: Please post the complete formula and give an minimal example. You do not need to post your actual work data but you can post example data which has the same structure as your work data.

Comment: Something like this